# Field not found, using object model library of Tfs 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Following code is giving me an exception:

```
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(_uri, credentials);
server.EnsureAuthenticated();
if (server.HasAuthenticated)
{
     this.store = server.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
}
```

**Exception:**

> Field not found:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IdentityAttributeTags.AccountName'

What could possibly be an issue behind this error?

Comment: I suspect you're missing a couple of dependent assemblies.

Comment: How could any dll be missed? Just done with the Visual Studio 2017 installation and this error popped up in my application.

Comment: Visual Studio no longer puts the dlls in the global assembly cache so your tools won't be able to find these without you adding the nuget package and including the assemblies in the project output.